# Do multimedia messages sent with iMessage impact data?

Tags: messages, sms

When I send a pictures from my iPhone (which has a SMS/MMS plan), does it impact data if I'm on a 4G network, and send it through iMessage?

Similarly, if I disable iMessage, then send an MMS over 4G, would it still use some data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iMessage is pure data usage, so yes it will affect your data.

MMS use depends on your carrier, but most charge a fixed fee per message, so it may be worth finding out the costs for this.

In the UK at least, there are many high data and unlimited data tariffs, so it's far better to replace all SMS and MMS with iMessage (or alternatives such as WhatsApp) where possible.

Comment: That makes sense. I forgot to mention I'm on AT&Ts unlimited texting plan, providing unlimited SMS and MMS. Would a MMS (with iMessage off) like that hit my data?

Comment: MMS uses a dedicated server to send and receive messages through which is auto configured via your SIM, so although it uses data, it's not via your general internet access, so won't count against your data usage.